# Formatting using \begin{questions}

Tags: exam, section-titles

I am writing a worksheet in overleaf with different questions in a 'questions' file and inserting them into the main document using

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\section{Question 1}
\include{Questions/1}
\section{Question 2}
\include{Questions/2}
\section{Question 3}
\include{Questions/3}
```

why do all my question numbers appear on separate pages to the actual question instead of them all being all together in one document?

Comment: Try changing `\include` with `\input`. The first one is thought for conditionally compiling chapters in a book (or similar long document) and issue a `\clearpage` or equivalent thing.